# Error when returning an ArrayType of StructType from UDF (and using a single function in multiple UDFs)

Tags: apache-spark

(EDIT) changed field names (from foo, bar,... to name and city) because old naming was confusing

I need to use a single function in multiple UDFs and return different Structs depending on the input.

This simplified version of my implementation basically does what I am looking for:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StructType, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col

df = spark.createDataFrame([1, 2, 3], IntegerType()).toDF('id')

struct_one = StructType().add('name', StringType(), True)
struct_not_one = StructType().add('city', StringType(), True)

def select(id):
  if id == 1:
    return {'name': 'Alice'}
  else:
    return {'city': 'Seattle'}

one_udf = udf(select, struct_one)
not_one_udf = udf(select, struct_not_one)

df = df.withColumn('one', when((col('id') == 1), one_udf(col('id'))))\
       .withColumn('not_one', when((col('id') != 1), not_one_udf(col('id'))))

display(df)
```

(EDIT) Output:

```
id  one               not_one
1   {"name":"Alice"}  null
2   null              {"city":"Seattle"}
3   null              {"city":"Seattle"}
```

But, the same code returning an ArrayType of StructType unfortunatly fails:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StructType, StringType, ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col

df = spark.createDataFrame([1, 2, 3], IntegerType()).toDF('id')

struct_one = StructType().add('name', StringType(), True)
struct_not_one = ArrayType(StructType().add('city', StringType(), True))

def select(id):
  if id == 1:
    return {'name': 'Alice'}
  else:
    return [{'city': 'Seattle'}, {'city': 'Milan'}]

one_udf = udf(select, struct_one)
not_one_udf = udf(select, struct_not_one)

df = df.withColumn('one', when((col('id') == 1), one_udf(col('id'))))\
       .withColumn('not_one', when((col('id') != 1), not_one_udf(col('id'))))

display(df)
```

The error message is:

> ValueError: Unexpected tuple 'name' with StructType

(EDIT) Desired Output would be:

```
id  one                 not_one
1   {"name":"Alice"}    null
2   null                [{"city":"Seattle"},{"city":"Milan"}]
3   null                [{"city":"Seattle"},{"city":"Milan"}]
```

Returning and ArrayType of other types (StringType, IntegerType,...) for example works, though.

Also returning an Array of StructType when not using a single function in multiple UDFs works:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StructType, StringType, ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col

df = spark.createDataFrame([1, 2, 3], IntegerType()).toDF('id')

struct_not_one = ArrayType(StructType().add('city', StringType(), True))

def select(id):
    return [{'city': 'Seattle'}, {'city': 'Milan'}]

not_one_udf = udf(select, struct_not_one)

df = df.withColumn('not_one', when((col('id') != 1), not_one_udf(col('id'))))

display(df)
```

(EDIT) Output:

```
id  not_one
1   null
2   [{"city":"Seattle"},{"city":"Milan"}]
3   [{"city":"Seattle"},{"city":"Milan"}]
```

Why is returning an ArrayType of StructType and using multiple UDFs with one single function not working?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share an example of input and desired output?

Comment: I have edited the outputs (+desired output) in the original post. The inputs are just the small sample dataframe created by the line:
df = spark.createDataFrame([1, 2, 3], IntegerType()).toDF('id')

Comment: Try this: ```df.withColumn("one", when(col("id") === 1, typedLit(Map("foo" -> "bar"))))
        .withColumn("not_one", when(col("id") =!= 1, typedLit(Map("foo" -> ("bar", "baz")))))```. Your "foo" : "bar" is a dictionary which is unique (key-wise), "foo" should appear only once with both values: "bar" & "baz"

Comment: Thanks Nir for your comment. I have changed the naming because it was kind of confusing. I unfortunatly cannot use typedLit() because in my actual implementation the select() function creates the return values dynamically. In the sample I simplified it an returned hard coded values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Spark SQL (including SQL and the DataFrame and Dataset API) does not guarantee the order of evaluation of subexpressions...
Therefore, it is dangerous to rely on the side effects or order of evaluation of Boolean expressions, and the order of WHERE and HAVING clauses, since such expressions and clauses can be reordered during query optimization and planning. Specifically, if a UDF relies on short-circuiting semantics in SQL for null checking, there’s no guarantee that the null check will happen before invoking the UDF."*

See [Evaluation order and null checking](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html#evaluation-order-and-null-checking)

To keep your udf generic you could push the 'when filter' into your udf:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StructType, StringType, ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, lit

df = spark.createDataFrame([1, 2, 3], IntegerType()).toDF('id')

struct_one = StructType().add('name', StringType(), True)
struct_not_one = ArrayType(StructType().add('city', StringType(), True))

def select(id, test):

  if eval(test.format(id)) is False:
    return None

  if id == 1:
    return {'name': 'Alice'}
  else:
    return [{'city': 'Seattle'}, {'city': 'Milan'}]

one_udf = udf(select, struct_one)
not_one_udf = udf(select, struct_not_one)

df = df.withColumn('one', one_udf(col('id'), lit('{} == 1')))\
       .withColumn('not_one', not_one_udf(col('id'), lit('{} != 1')))

display(df)
```